# What is the pressure under the lid of a rotating water bucket with lid?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics, fluid-statics

Consider a water bucket with lid, the water is in contact with the lid and the lid is tight to the bucket
[image]

The cross section of the bucket is circular, point A is the center of the circular section right below the lid. As you know, when the bucket was stationary (has no rotation), the pressure at point A was absolute zero. Now, when the bucket is in steady rotation at angular velocity $\omega$ about vertical axis through point A. I know the bucket now has parabolic pressure distribution and understand the math behind this but what is the pressure at point A now? How to know that?

Comment: "As you know, when the bucket was stationary (has no rotation), the pressure at point A was absolute zero." Who told you that?

Comment: @knzhou. I think because when the bucket was stationary we have something like vaccum at A. From the fact: pressure on the surface of the fluid is equal to that of air pressure above it, I conclude that pressure at A is zero. So how do you think? Did Ben's answer do great job?

Comment: Hmm, so if you pumped more and more water into this box, the pressure would never increase?

Comment: Ben's answer is perfectly correct, though it's building off this $P = 0$ assumption you're making, which doesn't make much sense.

Comment: if you pumped it, the pressure would increase. But my case is: when the lid is removed, the water level is exactly at the top of the bucket and then you gently put the lid on. Put Ben answer aside, how would you answer my question?

Comment: In that case it would be something closer to atmospheric pressure. Also, I agree with Ben.

Comment: @knzhou if we have vaccum at A, why is it close to atmospheric pressure ? Did you know the experiment with a glass of water and a playing card ?

Comment: How do you propose to gently put a lid on a box and create a vacuum in the process? Creating a vacuum is _difficult_, you need to _suck_ all the air out.

Comment: Even if you did somehow suck the air out, the water would immediately start to boil since the pressure is zero. So you wouldn't have a vacuum anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the water is perfectly incompressible and the container is perfectly rigid, the pressure at A is still ambient. Without rotation you get the pressure by integrating the body force from gravity, and you get $$P=-\rho g z$$ where $z$ is measured upwards from the top surface. With rotation, you also have to integrate the centrifugal force from the center outward, giving $$P=\rho (\frac{\omega^2 r^2}{2}-gz).$$ For $z=r=0$, $P=0$.

In reality, the container would stretch, and the water would compress, and there would actually open up a void at A. But we are assuming that doesn't happen. The added pressure from rotation adds up starting from the central axis. It doesn't add any pressure on the axis: it can't change it at A.

Comment: With rotation, the formula you have given is only at that form when you already assume pressure at A is zero. Because when you integrate, you have to provide a constant, and that constant is this case come from you are assuming pressure at A equals zero. You cannot use this formula to tell again the pressure at A is zero

Comment: You say "As you know" the pressure at A is zero with no rotation. How do you know that?  I am taking that as a given, so I know the constant of integration.

Comment: In reality, the container would stretch, and the water would compress, and there would actually open up a void at A.  But we are assuming that doesn't happen. The added pressure from rotation adds up starting from the central axis.  It doesn't add any pressure on the axis: it can't change it at A.

Comment: Ok, I will take your second comment as an answer.